# Getting exception of A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not proper ly respond after a period of time

Tags: java, socket.io, nio

I have created a NIO server, which receives 4000 device data at one port concurrently. Each device has a 30 sec interval to send data on server. My code inserts data into db by 600 to 1000 records in 1 or 2sec.

The data forwarded from another .net application server to my nio server.

And sometimes I'm getting the below error on the console of my .NET application:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   proper ly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   52.74.204.124:6000"

The NIO server code is below.

```
public class ServerSockets {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    int ports[] = new int[] {6000};
    Selector selector =Selector.open();

    // loop through each port in our list and bind it to a ServerSocketChannel
    for (int port : ports) {
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        // selector = Selector.open();
        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    }
    Set keys=null;
    SelectionKey key=null;
    String REQUEST_DATA = null;
    String remoteAddress = null;
    String device_ip = null;
    String device_port = null;
    //check for all port whom ready to send data
    while (true) {

        try {
            // loop over all the sockets that are ready for some activity

            while (selector.select()>0) {
                keys= selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator i = keys.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    key = (SelectionKey)i.next();
                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        // this means that a new client has hit the port our main
                        // socket is listening on, so we need to accept the  connection
                        // and add the new client socket to our select pool for reading
                        // a command later
                        //System.out.println("Accepting connection!");

                        //FETCH DB DATA 
                        //DatabaseActivity databaseActivity = new DatabaseActivity();
                        //databaseActivity.db_mongoFetch("jj_tracking");

                        // this will be the ServerSocketChannel we initially registered
                        // with the selector in main()
                        ServerSocketChannel sch = (ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();
                        SocketChannel ch = sch.accept();
                        ch.configureBlocking(false);
                        ch.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                        // one of our client sockets has received a command and
                        // we're now ready to read it in
                        SocketChannel ch=null;
                        try
                        {
                            //System.out.println("Accepting command!");                            
                            ch = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                            remoteAddress = String.valueOf(ch.getRemoteAddress());
                            //System.out.println("LOCAL ADDRESS 5 ---> "+remoteAddress);                             
                            if(remoteAddress !=null && remoteAddress.length() > 0){
                                String[] remoteAddressArr = remoteAddress.split(":");
                                if(remoteAddressArr.length > 0){
                                    device_ip = remoteAddressArr[0].substring(1);
                                    device_port = remoteAddressArr[1];
                                }
                            }
                            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8024);
                            ch.read(buf);

                            if(buf.position()>0){
                                buf.flip();
                                System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                                System.out.println("REQEST_STRING =>  "+new String(buf.array()));
                                System.out.print("HEX_STRING =>  "+convertToHex(buf.array(),buf.limit())+"\n\n");

                                //String REQUEST_DATA_STRING  = new String(buf.array());
                                //System.out.println("ORIGNAL REQUEST STRING => "+REQUEST_DATA_STRING);

                                /**
                                 * 
                                 * CONDITION FOR TK06 [ NEW ALTRA ]
                                 * FETCH IMEI NUMBER THAT ATTACHED WITH REQUEST STRING
                                 * SEPERATOR "~##~"
                                 * 
                                 * */
                                /*if(REQUEST_DATA_STRING.contains("~##~")){

                                    String[] REQUEST_DATA_ARR = REQUEST_DATA_STRING.split("~##~");
                                    String imei_number = REQUEST_DATA_ARR[0].trim();
                                    //REQUEST_DATA = new String(convertToHex(String.valueOf(REQUEST_DATA_ARR[1]).getBytes(),buf.limit())).trim();

                                    REQUEST_DATA = REQUEST_DATA +"~@@@~"+ imei_number;
                                    System.out.println("PROCESSED STRING => "+REQUEST_DATA);

                                }else{// NORMAL CASE FOR OTHER DEVICE
                                    //ACTUAL CODE
                                    REQUEST_DATA = new String(convertToHex(buf.array(),buf.limit())).trim();
                                    //FOR TESTNG ON ABHISHEK SYS
                                    //REQUEST_DATA = new String(buf.array()).trim();                                        
                                }*/

                                // OLD CODE
                                //ACTUAL CODE
                                REQUEST_DATA = new String(convertToHex(buf.array(),buf.limit())).trim();
                                //FOR TESTNG ON ABHISHEK SYS
                                //REQUEST_DATA = new String(buf.array()).trim();

                                if(REQUEST_DATA != null && !REQUEST_DATA.isEmpty()){
                                    ProcessRequest processRequest = new ProcessRequest();
                                    processRequest.processRequestString(REQUEST_DATA, device_ip, device_port);
                                }                                   
                            }else{
                                key.channel().close();
                                ch.close();
                            }
                        }catch(IOException E){
                            key.cancel();
                            ch.close();
                        }

                        /*  Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                            CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                            CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(buf);
                            System.out.print(cbuf.toString());*/
                        //  re-register this socket with the selector, this time
                        //  for writing since we'll want to write something to it
                        //  on the next go-around
                        //  ch.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    }
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in poll loop");
            System.out.println();

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the scalability of this application. The code processes everything in single thread (the main one which also handles the acceptance of new connections).

If processing of incoming data took too much time it would result into long queue of clients waiting for accepting their connections and further request might be rejected by underlying operating system.

I suggest using either nio2 with asynchronous completion handlers or some high level framework like Apache Mina or Netty.

PS: Additionally, note that the code above has more problems, especially managing the read operation of buffer - it needs to somehow check whether the client already sent all data as might be fragmented by network layer. With http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html you can make sure by repeating the reads until you have full message.